# Why is an output field not displayed on display file?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am working on a display field which displays a bunch of stuff (as they always do, obviously). Recently I have encountered a very strange scenario. I have added one more character output field in one record format, but somehow this field cannot be displayed when this record format is written onto screen. I have checked under debug mode. The value has been assigned to the field before the EXFMT statement, but it just never gets shown. I have move it to somewhere else in the record format, and the problem persists. I have also tried to move it to another record format which is displayed on the same screen, and this time it works. What could have gone wrong to result in such scenario?

```
      R XT99901                SFLCTL(XT99902)
                               SFLSIZ(0011)
                               SFLPAG(0005)
                               SFLDSP
                               SFLDSPCTL
02                             SFLCLR
03                             SFLEND
                               BLINK
                               LOCK
                               PUTOVR
                               OVERLAY
                               CA05
    .
    .
    .
                           4  2'Status'     
        S1STUS     15A  O  4 14COLOR(RED)
```

Field S1STUS is the one with problem.

Comment: Check the error messages in the DDS compiler listing.  Specifically, messages indicating overlapping fields.  If that doesn't help, post enough DDS so that someone can compile the DDS and re-create the problem.

Comment: There is no overlapping field, but there is one message CPD8111 saying the record might not be able to be displayed. What does it mean?

Comment: If you have a record with LOCK but not FRCDTA, and you create the file DFRWRT(*YES) (which is rare), that record may not be displayed because of the deferred write.

Comment: I have LOCK in that record but did not CRTDSPF with DFRWRT(*YES), at least I used the default value. And I only have one field which cannot be displayed. The rest have no such problem.

Comment: Right, the CPD8111 would involve the whole record, not just one field.

Comment: So the cause should be somewhere else then? I have actually tried to remove other fields in the same record to make sure there is no other to overlap with, and it still could not be seen. It could be seen if moved to other record format, which means its definition should not be wrong, and the value was assigned to it successfully. What else could cause the problem?

Comment: Very difficult to say without seeing all the DDS.

Comment: I have posted part of the DDS, please take a look.

Comment: Since this record format is a subfile control record, is line 15 on or below your first subfile record in XT99902?

Comment: For the subfile record, you actually meant line 5 or below, right? S1STUS is on line 4 at position 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [PUTOVR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzakc/rzakcmstdfputov.htm), you will need to specify [OVRDTA](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzakc/rzakcmstdfovdta.htm) on every output field you want to change.  Add the OVRDTA keyword to S1STUS and see if that helps.

Comment: I actually have other output only fields in the same record format without OVRDTA keyword, and they work fine. And I have tried adding one to S1STUS before and it did not help. In fact I had once changed this field into input/output. The value still did not get shown, but if I enter something in that field and press enter, this value would remain there. Strange.

Comment: You need to read the manual for PUTOVR.  Other keywords perform an implicit OVRDTA.  To help debug this, remove PUTOVR and all the OVRDTA keywords and see if that helps.  If it does not, post ALL of the DDS so that we can try to re-create it.

Comment: Somehow OVRDTA solved the problem in the end, though it did not work before... But never mind, it works now. Thanks.